# Xpressive >>= Operator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-xpressive

I am toying around with Boost Xpressive and am having trouble with the following snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::xpressive;

int main()
{
    string s("123");
    sregex rex = _d;
    rex >>= _d;

    smatch what;

    regex_search(s, what, rex);

    cout << "Match: " << what[0] << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

The result of running this program is a match of `1` as opposed to the expected `12`. Does the `sregex::operator>>=` have a different meaning/use what I intuitively assumed? I was expecting this to yield an `sregex` similar to `_d >> _d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpressive doesn't support the >>= operator. The fact that this code compiles at all could be considered a bug. Try:

```
rex = rex >> _d;
```

However, building up a regex piecemeal like this will make the regex perform poorly.